# Why is my code returning commas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, transpose

After running this code my return has a bunch of "," 's:

```js
function transposeTwoStrings(arr) {
  var arr1 = arr[0];
  var arr2 = arr[1];
  var largerArray;

  if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    largerArray = arr1;
  } else if (arr1 < arr2) {
    largerArray = arr2;
  }

  var array = new Array(3);
  for (var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array(3);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] === undefined) {
      array += (" " + " " + arr2[i] + "\n");
    } else {
      array += (arr1[i] + " " + arr2[i] + "\n");
    }
  }
  return array;

}

var result = transposeTwoStrings(["Te", "xts"]);

console.log(result);
```

Should Return "T x\ne t\n  s"
Instead I get ",,,,,,,,T x
e t
  s
"

Comment: You're calling your function incorrectly to start. It should be `transposeTwoStrings(["Te","xts"]);`

Comment: With the code you've posted I get [`,,,,T e`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rqv48kjp/); assuming you simply forgot to pass an Array of Strings (rather than the two Strings you pass in the question's code), *then* I get your described [`,,,,,,,,T x
\ne t\n  s`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rqv48kjp/). Also you've provided no condition for what should happen if both Arrays are the same length.

Comment: Think about it, `array` is an array with three empty slots, then you suddenly treat it as a string doing `array += ...` and the stringified version is suddenly `,,`

Comment: `(new Array(3) + "") === ",,"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix many issues to get the output.
1. Need to pass the arguments in [] at the call site so that the called function could extract values at 0 and 1 indices.
2. Don't use += operator on `array`, instead use [] operator.
3. You are hardcoding the size of array that you return from the function to 3, don't do that.

See the code below:

```js
function transposeTwoStrings(arr) {
  var arr1 = arr[0];
  var arr2 = arr[1];
  var largerArray;

  if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    largerArray = arr1;
  } else if (arr1 < arr2) {
    largerArray = arr2;
  }

  //var array = new Array(3);
  var array = [];
  //for (var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i++) {
  //    array[i] = new Array(3);
  //}
  for (var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] === undefined) {
      array[i] = (" " + " " + arr2[i] + "\n");
    } else {
      array[i] = (arr1[i] + " " + arr2[i] + "\n");
    }
  }
  return array;

}

var result = transposeTwoStrings(["Te", "xts"]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work with the help of everyone else; I ended up getting :

```
    function transposeTwoStrings(arr) {
var arr1 = arr[0];
var arr2 = arr[1];
var largerArray;

if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    largerArray = arr1;
} else if (arr1.length  < arr2.length) {
    largerArray = arr2;
} else if (arr1.length == arr2.length){
    largerArray = arr1;
}

var transposed = "";

for (var i = 0; i < largerArray.length; i++){
    //If arr1[i] is blank and [i] is not at the end of the array 
    if (arr1[i] === undefined && i != largerArray.length - 1){
        transposed += (" " + " " + arr2[i] + "\n");
    //If arr1[i] is blank and [i] IS at the end of the array    
    } else if (arr1[i] === undefined && i == largerArray.length - 1){
        transposed += (" " + " " + arr2[i]);
    //If arr2[i] is blank and [i] is NOT at the end of the array    
    } else if (arr2[i] === undefined && i != largerArray.length - 1){
        transposed += (arr1[i] + " " + " " + "\n");
    //If arr2[i] is blank and [i] IS at the end of the array    
    } else if (arr2[i] === undefined && i == largerArray.length - 1){
        transposed += (arr1[i] + " " + " ");
    //If [i] is at the end of the array    
    } else if (i == largerArray.length - 1){
        transposed += (arr1[i] + " " + arr2[i]);
    //If [i] is not at the end of the array    
    } else {
        transposed += (arr1[i] + " " + arr2[i])+ "\n";

    }
}
return transposed;

}
```

I know its not amazing.

I'm not close to being a programmar, I know.

I thank everyone that helped!